# Not sure what im supposed to do using StringBuilder

Tags: java, methods, stringbuilder

I'm being asked to provide my own implementations in a new class for the methods listed below. I'm not sure what i am supposed to do with them. Any ideas? I just recently switched over to java from using C++. Most area are at least somewhat similar between the two but I am having difficulty with strings and methods.

---

Okay that all makes sense but what am i supposed to do with these methods? like the first one "public MystringBuilder1(String s)". is that just declaring the variable "s" as a string type? and how do i implement it? If you put "public MystringBuilder1(String s)" in a class it just comes back with an error. The book never explained any of those methods and then said "here do this" so i am totally lost. Maybe im just missing the point?

```
public MyStringBuilder1(String s);

public MyStringBuilder1 append(MyStringBuilder1 s);

public MyStringBuilder1 append(int i);

public String toString();
```

Comment: Maybe you should ask the person who told you to do it what they want you to do.

Comment: You should provide your current attempt. If one does not exist you should at least give it a shot first.

Comment: `public MystringBuilder1(String s)` isn't a method, it's a constructor.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. That helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the StringBuilder class in the Java API is to  construct strings more efficiently than the native string class. This might be useful if you are processing a lot of data in a loop and storing it in a string. Java's native string class is immutable, which means when two strings are concatenated they must both be copied to create a new string. Immutable strings have a few advantages, but speed isn't one of them.

What this assignment is probably asking is for you to make your own implementation of this class. Find a data structure that allows you to both efficiently append new strings to your class and can also be turned into a string when the toString method is called, then implement the required methods around this data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The StringBuilder class really helps when you want to concatenate many strings where several assignments take place.(For example: within a loop)

Say for example you have this:

```
string firstString = "first" + "second";
```

This statement will create a new string with size equal to ("first".length()+"second".length()) and copy both of the strings to the new string.

The strength of the StringBuilder class comes when you are doing for example:

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(string str:strings){
    strBuilder.append(str);
}
strBuilder.toString();
```

Instead of:

```
String wholeString = "";
for(string str:strings){
     wholeString += str;
}
```

This is very inefficient since for every iteration of the loop a new string is created for every concatenation.

StringBuilder class will keep track of each string in the concatenation and will not create a new string as you append to it. So you can concatenate 10 strings  by using the `append` method 10 times and only 1 string will be created when you call the `toString` method.

Comment: This is incorrect; if you have `foo + bar + baz` strings, the compiler will create a single StringBuilder to concat them all. The real strength of explicitly using StringBuilder is when each concatenation is in a different statement -- and especially when those concatenations are in a loop.

Comment: @yshavit Is it like that for an optimized compiler or all java compilers?

Comment: And when you say in a loop, you mean there are several assignments I suppose?

Comment: I don't think it's required by the spec, but javac does it, for instance, and its optimizations are very minimal (most optimizations go in the JVM/JIT). And yeah, several assignments. For instance, `for (e : elems ) { str += e.toString(); }` would be better with a StringBuilder.

Comment: Okay thanks for the note, I learnt something new, will fix!